# Redirect to another page with all current param

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I want to redirect in C# ASP from old page to new one with all the params after the "**.aspx?**"

https://www.MySite.org1/order/buynow_1.aspx?c=FR&n=1&__utma=010101._7578795abc75689756.4&__utmb=az56786238.2........

https://www.MySite.org1/order/buynow_2.aspx?c=FR&n=1&__utma=010101._7578795abc75689756.4&__utmb=az56786238.2........

I tried to redirect with the first params that I know c=FR , n=1 
but how can I pass all the value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the code shown below in `buynow_1.aspx` as both `buynow_1.aspx` and `buynow_2.aspx` are in the same folder `order`, so no need to include `order` in the `url`.

```
 Response.Redirect("buynow_2.aspx" + Request.Url.Query);
```

Comment: Thanks! 'Request.Url.Query' was the answer

Answer (score 0):

From where(html click, code behind click, function click ...) do you want to redirect, too little info in the question. If you are doing it on button click ,or at the end of a function etc (in the code) do something like this:

```
string cStr= Request.QueryString["c"];
string nStr= Request.QueryString["n"];
```

etc for all your querystring variables. Then do this:

```
Response.Redirect("/order/buynow_2.aspx?c="+cStr+"&n="+nStr");
```